# "update controller" from FXML in IntellIJ for javaFX project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I used to see the option "update controller" in the menu after right-clicking on an FXML file generated by scene builder in a JavaFX project but now it disappeared, how to make that appear?

[image: FXML file]

Comment: There is no mention of such a feature that I can find in intellij documentation.  I also don't ever recall seeing such a menu item, though I never looked for one before.  Perhaps it was a feature of idea which was removed from recent versions of the product.

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for your response but trust me it was there "update controller" or something like that but it was removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [FXML Manager](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14854-fxmlmanager) plugin might be what you are looking for:

- go to `File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Marketplace` and search & install **FXML Manager**:

[image]

- after installing it, you may use the update controller option:

[image]